# I am no longer able to debug/run my SharePoint Remote Event Receiver locally using Ngrok

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, remote-event-receiver, reverse-proxy

Last month the below steps were working well for me to debug and test a SharePoint online remote event receiver locally:-

1. Open Ngrok.exe >> run the following command inside ngrok:-

> ```
>  ngrok authtoken 3***e
>  ngrok http --host-header=rewrite  57269
> ```

2. register a new app:- @ `https://.sharepoint.com/sites//_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx` >> enter the above Ngrok urls inside the `App Redirect URL` & `App Domain`.
3. Inside the `_layouts/15/appinv.aspx` >> I search for the above app using `Client ID` >> and enter the following:-

> ```
>  <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
>    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
>  </AppPermissionRequests>
> ```

5. Update the service's web config with the above `ClientID` and `ClientSecret`
6. Register the new remove event receiver as follow:-

> ```
>  Add-PnPEventReceiver -List "Order Management" -Name "TasksRER" -Url http://cc6e945e82f6.ngrok.io/service1.svc -EventReceiverType ItemUpdated -Synchronization Asynchronous
> ```

But today when I tried the above steps it failed >> where inside my event receiver when I tried to get the SharePoint context >> I will get that the Context is null:-

```
  public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
         {
             var prop = properties;
             var listItemID = properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId;
             var listTitle = properties.ItemEventProperties.ListTitle;
             using (ClientContext context = Helpers.GetAppOnlyContext(properties.ItemEventProperties.WebUrl))
             {
                 context.Load(context.Web);
                 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Here is a screen shot from Visual Studio with the error i am getting when trying to get the context:-

[image]

Any advice if anything has been changed which is preventing me from running the above steps? which were working well last month?
Thanks

here is the code for the GetAppOnlyContext

```
     public class Helpers
         {
             public static ClientContext GetAppOnlyContext(string siteUrl)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     Uri siteUri = new Uri(siteUrl);
                     string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri);
                     string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;
        
                     return TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(siteUri.ToString(), accessToken);
                 }
        
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Trace.TraceInformation("GetAppOnlyContext failed. {0}", ex.Message);
                 }
                 return null;
             }
        
             public static ClientContext GetAuthenticatedContext(string siteUrl)
             {
                 string userName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AuthenticatedUserName");
                 string password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AuthenticatedUserPassword");
                 return GetAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, userName, password);
             }
        
             public static ClientContext GetAuthenticatedContext(string siteUrl, string userName, SecureString password)
             {
                 ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
                 ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);
                 return ctx;
             }
        
             public static ClientContext GetAuthenticatedContext(string siteUrl, string userName, string password)
             {
                 SecureString securePassword = GetPassword(password);
                 return GetAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, userName, securePassword);
             }
        
             private static SecureString GetPassword(string passwd)
             {
                 var secure = new SecureString();
                 foreach (char c in passwd)
                 {
                     secure.AppendChar(c);
                 }
                 return secure;
             }
        
             public static string EmptyIfNull(object obj)
             {
                 return obj == null ? "" : obj.ToString();
             }
         }
     }
```

seem this statement `string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;` inside my `Helpers.GetAppOnlyContext` will raise this error `token request failed`, as follow:-

[image]